# Time bug in badges page

Tags: bug, badges, timestamps

I'm not [living in the future](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/living-in-the-future) (yet), but I just hit rep-cap on my main site for the 50<sup>th</sup> time and was awarded the [epic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) badge (yay!) - but the badge page seems to think the system awarded me the badge some 20 hours ago:

[image: Awarded 20h ago? Really??]

The tooltip over the "20h ago" is saying 2015-12-15 00:00:00Z, which explains the bug: looks like the actual timestamp gets lost somewhere in the way to the database, throwing off the "X hours ago" label.

Comment: Too good to be true.

Comment: Wow bug of the day.